# Rxjs: Angular draggable rectangle difference mouse response to Typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, response, drag

I'm playing around with RxJS and Angular with an example of draggable rectangle but I don't understand why the mouse response it is better in case of Typescript than Angular. **note: I think the problem is that Angular let me do MouseUp outside the rectangle and this does not happen with Typescript*

There must be something I'm missing. Is there anything else I should consider of?

I tried to look it up on the internet and I just found how to do it with cdk library or with more complex rxjs operators. My first intention is to build it as simple as it is right now. Any idea?

Here my examples:

- Typescript: https://stackblitz.com/edit/rectangle-drag-angular
- Angular: https://stackblitz.com/edit/rectangle-drag-ts

I paste here the code for each one just in case someone prefer it:

**Typescript example:**

```
draggable: HTMLElement;

let draggable = <HTMLElement>document.querySelector("#draggable");

let mouseDown$ = fromEvent<MouseEvent>(draggable, "mousedown");
let mouseMove$ = fromEvent<MouseEvent>(document, "mousemove");
let mouseUp$ = fromEvent<MouseEvent>(document, "mouseup");

mouseDown$.subscribe(() => {
  mouseMove$
    .pipe(
      map(event => {
        event.preventDefault();
        return {
          x: event.clientX,
          y: event.clientY
        };
      }),
      tap(console.log),
      takeUntil(mouseUp$)
    )
    .subscribe(pos => {
      // Draggable is absolutely positioned
      draggable.style.left = pos.x + "px";
      draggable.style.top = pos.y + "px";
    });
});
```

**Angular example:**

```
export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit, OnInit {
  draggable: HTMLElement;
  mouseDown$: Observable<MouseEvent>;
  mouseMove$: Observable<MouseEvent>;
  mouseUp$: Observable<MouseEvent>;


  ngOnInit() {
    this.draggable = <HTMLElement>document.getElementById("draggable");
    this.mouseDown$ = fromEvent<MouseEvent>(this.draggable, "mousedown");
    this.mouseMove$ = fromEvent<MouseEvent>(this.draggable, "mousemove");
    this.mouseUp$ = fromEvent<MouseEvent>(this.draggable, "mouseup");
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.mouseDown$.subscribe(() => {
      this.mouseMove$
        .pipe(
          map(event => {
            event.preventDefault();
            return {
              x: event.clientX,
              y: event.clientY
            };
          }),
          tap(console.log),
          takeUntil(this.mouseUp$)
        )
        .subscribe(pos => {
          this.draggable.style.left = pos.x + "px";
          this.draggable.style.top = pos.y + "px";
        });
    });
  }
```

Comment: What does it mean "better"?

Comment: I apologize if is not clear.. If you drag the rectangle you can see different behaviour when you move it on one side compare to the other. In angular seems to get stuck and in Typescript it moves smoothly. I edit the post with a note. Thanks!